# If roots of $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ form an arithmetic sequence, then $2a^3 + 27c = 9ab$

Tags: polynomials

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588140/prove-that-if-2a3-27c-9ab-then-the-roots-of-x3-ax2-bx-c-0-fo) we have to prove that if $2a^3 + 27c = 9ab,$ then the roots of
$$x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$ form an arithmetic sequence.

What if we wanted to prove the opposite, that if we are given that the roots of the polynomial $$x^3+ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$ form an arithmetic sequence, then prove that $2a^3 + 27c = 9ab$.

---

My work so far:

suppose the roots are $q, r,$ and $s$ and the arithmetic sequence they form is in that order. This means $2r = q + s$. I have tried doing something using Vieta's but I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Prove that if $2a^3 + 27c = 9ab,$ then the roots of $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ form an arithmetic sequence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3588140). At least my answer seems to show both directions.

Comment: No, it isn't a duplicate. I didn't understand your solution very well. Sorry.

Comment: This question is not an exact duplicate of the question I mentioned; it is the converse. However, my answer to the other question shows both directions. I have added a bit more to that answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that if the roots are in an arithmetic sequence, they can be expressed as $\alpha-\beta,\alpha,\alpha+\beta.$ Thus, we have $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=(x-\alpha+\beta)(x-\alpha)(x-\alpha-\beta)=0.$

Comparing coefficients, we have $a=-3\alpha, b=(-\alpha+\beta)(-\alpha)+(-\alpha+\beta)(-\alpha-\beta)+(-\alpha)(-\alpha-\beta), c=(-\alpha+\beta)\alpha(-\alpha-\beta).$

The equation you give can be proved by substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The roots satisfy,

$$x_1+x_2+x_3=-a\tag 1$$

Given that they form an arithmetic sequence,

$$x_1+x_3 = 2x_2$$

Plug into (1) to get,

$$x_2=-\frac a3$$

and substitute the root $x_2$ into the cubic equation $x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ to obtain,

$$2a^3 + 27c = 9ab$$

Answer (score 1):

$2a^3+27c=9ab$

We have $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$

Let, Arithmetic series, $ A-D ~~ A ~~ A+D$ be the roots.

Then, Sum of roots, $ A - D + A + A + D = - a/1 \Rightarrow A = - a/3 $

Product of roots, $(A + D) A (A - D) = - c/1 \Rightarrow$

Substitute A,$(A^2 - D^2) = - 3c/-a = 3c/a\\$

Sum of Product of two consecutive roots, $A(A - D)+ A (A + D) + (A + D)(A - D) = b/1$

$A^2 - AD + A^2 + AD + A^2 - D^2 = b$

$2A^2 + A^2 - D^2 = b$
Substitute values

$\frac{2a^2}{9}+\frac{3c}{a} = b$

$2a^3+27c = 9ab$

Comment: Please leave normal text outside of math mode.