# How to apply Vieta's formulas to $y^3-\frac{a^2y}{3}+by+\frac{2a^3}{27}-\frac{ba}{3}+c$?

Tags: polynomials

I am not sure how to apply Vieta's to $y^3-\frac{a^2y}{3}+by+\frac{2a^3}{27}-\frac{ba}{3}+c$. I'm not sure which one to use...

Comment: What is the question exactly? What is your motivation for using these formulae?

Comment: I'm solving a problem (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588140/prove-that-if-2a3-27c-9ab-then-the-roots-of-x3-ax2-bx-c-0-fo) on my own and I found that i must use Vieta's (sorry for the unclear question)

Comment: You shouldn't need Vieta's formulae as shown from the top answer there. Using the condition provided you can show that the constant in the polynomial you have above is zero. Then you can factor $y$ and solve for the two other roots.